# Incorrect username and password with Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, soapui, soap-client

I am new to SOAPUI.  So far; I have created the default WCF project in Visual Studio; published it to IIS and then tested it in SOAPUI.  This worked as expected.

I am now trying to test a simple WCF Service, which uses Basic Authentication.  I can test this WCF Service (with Basic Authentication) in a C# program as follows (this works as expected):

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client s1 = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            s1.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "testuser";
            s1.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "testpassword";
            string str = s1.GetData(1);

        }
```

I am now trying to test this in SOAPUI.  I have the following setup:

[image]

Note I have already right clicked and selected: Add WSS Username Token and selected: PasswordText.

I have also gone to: File/Preferences/HTTP Settings and selected: "adds authentication information to outgoing request".

What is the problem?

Comment: Tried with `Authenticate pre-emptively`? or any proxy sitting? any headers missing?

Comment: @Rao, yes I tried that and got the same error.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Rao, or anyone else - what else can I do? I have spent hours looking at this.

Comment: Does anyone have any other suggestions? I have spent a full day researching this.  Please help.

Comment: @Rao, what do you mean by Proxy Sitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spent a long time trying to get the Auth window to work.

Instead I have done this, which works:

1.In the Request window, select the “Headers” tab on the bottom left.

2.Click the “+” button to add a header. The name of the header must be “Authorization.” Click OK.

3.In the value box, enter the word “Basic” plus the base64-encoded username:password. Use a base 64 encoder/decoder tool to create the base64 user:password string. For example, the Base64 version of “testuser:testpwd” is “dGVzdHVzZXI6dGVzdHB3ZA==” so the Value for the header would be  Basic dGVzdHVzZXI6dGVzdHB3ZA==

I found the instructions here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPVUA_10.0.0/com.ibm.mdshs.esoatoolkit.doc/topics/t_esoatoolkit_createsoapUIhttpbasicauth.html

Here is a base64 encoder I used: https://www.base64encode.org/